# ERROR 1452: Can not add or update a child row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have tables doctor and department. The M:1 relationship between doctor and department means that the doctor can work in one department, whereas the department can have many doctors. Therefore, department is referenced in the doctor's table. The specific doctor is also a director of the department.  Therefore doctor's emp_no (The doctor inherits emp_no from superclass employee) is referenced in deprartment.
[image: Here are the tables]
I have this insert statement for department.

```
INSERT INTO department (dept_name, Doctor_emp_no) 
VALUES ('Cardiology', (SELECT emp_no 
                      FROM employee WHERE 
                     specialty = 'Interventional Cardiologist' 
                     AND f_name = 'Oliver' and l_name = 'Adams'));
```

However, it gives me

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hsp`.`doctor`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Doctor_department1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_dept_no`) REFERENCES `department` (`dept_no`))

I assume that even though doctor has emp_no as primary key, the insertion is not possible because I don't have records in doctor table. But I need to insert data in department in order to insert data in doctor table.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: from the image it is hard to tell all your foreign keys

Comment: I updated the picture. Hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: OOPs looks like you have a nasty circular reference going on you may have to temporarily disable foreign key checks and review your design.

Comment: department_dept_no has nothing to do with your department  so please post all your create tables

Comment: department_dept_no is a foreign key, which references the department primary key - dept_no

Comment: @P.Salmon Does it mean that the design is bad? I just didn't know how to show the above-explained relationships without the circular reference.

Comment: Consider a junction table

Comment: I think I need to allow null values in foreign keys and then update the Null values with proper ones. Is it a good solution for this situation?

Comment: post not a table instead  a creatwe table as text, your design has flaws, that are not cleared by your image